# Books for learning horn clause logic

Tags: programming-languages, prolog

I want to learn prolog,two reason for that are -one can always find a counter example to the argument by searching for negation.So,one can learn by debugging the scripts.I heard that prolog is based on horn clause logic ,so want to learn more about it.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn_clause, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn-satisfiability

Answer (score 1):

> I want to learn prolog.

While I would not recommend learning Prolog on your own, if one insist then one of the better places to learn is from

[Learn Prolog Now!](http://www.let.rug.nl/bos/lpn//)

---

> So, one can learn by debugging the scripts.

If you want to try Prolog online without installing Prolog use [SWISH](https://swish.swi-prolog.org). To debug Prolog use [trace/1](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=trace/1) or [gtrace/0](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=gtrace/0).

---

> Books for learning horn clause logic

To learn Prolog one does not need to dig into [Horn clauses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Horn_clause) in detail. Understanding them is helpful at times. I have been programming in Prolog daily for a few years now and only when I am trying to understand the inner workings of Prolog do I really think about Horn clauses.

---

For other books and such related to Prolog see:

[Useful Prolog references](https://swi-prolog.discourse.group/t/useful-prolog-references/1089)